# Making Media Folder Accessible To Public

Tags: django

How do you make your media folder accessible to the public? I have pictures inside the media folder that I want public.

Also, do you have to use python library calls to manually delete all files put into the media folder once you are done processing them? Or is there some Django support for this?

Also, I'm not too familiar with how databases work, but I'm trying to store images inside models with an ImageField. I noticed that even though these models are stored in a database, their images are still stored locally through media/image.png. Is this fine? Is the primary purpose of having a database in web development to easily query and organize your data?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: " I'm not too familiar with how databases work, but I'm trying to store images inside models with an ImageField." unless you are using a map/reduce file system , this is a very stupid an inefficient idea. You static assets should stay in a content delivery network where you upload them amazon s3 , etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue on the web server.

If you are using `nginx` try this,

```
  location /media {
      alias /your_full_path/media;
   }
```

If you are using `apache2` try this,

```
   Alias /media /your_full_path/media
   <Directory /your_full_path/media>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
```